# Understanding a Python language feature

Tags: python

First, the Python code snippet in question (only one line matters, but thought I'd give full usage context):

```
1        queue=deque([(0,'')])
2        nq=deque([])
3        tree=trie()
4        output=[]
5        
6        for word in wordDict:
7            tree.insert(word)
8           
9        while queue:
10            for _ in range(len(queue)):
11                start,path=queue.popleft()
12                for end in range(start,len(s)+1):
13                    if tree.search(s[start:end]):
14                        nq.append((end,path+s[start:end]+' '))
15                        if end==len(s):
16                            output.append(path+s[start:end])
17            queue,nq=nq,deque([])
18        return output
```

My question is in regard to line 17:

```
queue,nq=nq,deque([])
```

It's functionally equivalent to this:

```
if len(queue) == 0:
    queue = nq
    nq = deque([])
```

Can someone explain how line 17 is functionally equivalent to it? i.e. `queue = nq` and `nq = deque([])` doesn't happen unless queue is empty. What makes `queue,nq=nq,deque([])` achieve the same thing? Thanks.

[Edit] I didn't understand that this line is simply setting values to a tuple (Python noob) as many of you have pointed out. Thought it was some weird Python operator involving 3 entities `queue`,`nq=nq`, and `deque([])`, lol. And the `if` statement was my interpretation of what it should be translated to and just my dumb luck, it happened to make the code still work. You folks are correct, the `if` has nothing to do with it, it'd work without it. Thanks all.

Comment: There's no `if` there, neither behaviourally nor implicitly.

Comment: You've changed 'semantically' to 'functionally', but the code is still not the same - even though it may have the same outcome in some situations. What you're asking about is basic tuple unpacking though, the same as `a, b = 1, 2` being the same as `a = 1` and `b = 2`. Perhaps you're confused by the fact that the `,` here has greater operator precedence than `=` and thus `a, b = 1, 2` should be read as `(a, b) = (1, 2)`

Comment: *"doesn't happen unless queue is empty"* — Why do you think so?

Comment: Why do you think `queue,nq=nq,deque([])` doesn't do anything unless `queue` is empty?

Comment: I can't think of any good reason that line is written like that, unless it made sense in an earlier version, but was refactored into the current form. The loop uses up elements from `queue`, and at the same time populates an empty (generally smaller) `nq` ("next queue"?). At the end `nq` becomes the queue to operate on and `nq` is reinitialized to empty.

Answer (score 1):

The right side of the assignment, `nq,deque([])`, is creating a tuple.  The left side, `queue,nq=` is using *tuple unpacking* to assign the elements of that tuple to individual variables.